# OpenMP 4.5 task dependencies and execution order

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to get OpenMP task dependencies to work, to no avail.
Let's take this simplified example:

```
int main()
{
int x=0;

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
#pragma omp task depend(in:x)
  {
  #pragma omp critical
  cout << "Read the value " << x << "\n";
  }
#pragma omp task depend(out:x)
  {
  x = 3;
  #pragma omp critical
  cout << "Set the value to " << x << "\n";
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand (frome OpenMP specs), the depend(in:x) tasks should only be executed after all depend(out:x) tasks have been resolved, and so the expected output is

```
Set the value to 3
Read the value 3
```

However, the tasks are instead executed in semantic order, disregarding the depend clauses, and what I get is this:

```
Read the value 0
Set the value to 3
```

I am compiling using g++-7 (SUSE Linux) 7.3.1 20180323 [gcc-7-branch revision 258812] with the -fopenmp flag. This version of the compiler should have access to OpenMP 4.5.

Is this a misunderstanding of task dependencies on my side, or is there anything else at play here?

Comment: Are you sure that you can stack the initial pragmas like that? I only see examples of a new block being started per pragma...

Comment: @MaxLanghof If you refer to the two pragmas at the begining (omp parallel and omp single), yes that's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of task dependencies can be misleading.

The best way to put it is to think about them as a way to indicate **how different tasks access data** and not as a way to control **execution order**.

The order of the tasks in the source code, together with the depend clause, describe one of the possibile 4 scenarios: *read after write*, *write after read*, *write after write* and *read after read*.

In your example, you are describing a **write after read** case: you are telling the compiler that the second task will overwrite the variable x, but the first task takes x as an input, as indicated by `depend(in:x)`. Therefore, the software will execute the first task before the second **to prevent overwriting** the initial value.

If you have a look at Intel's documentation [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524540) there's a brief example which shows how tasks order (in the source code) still plays a role in the determination of the dependency graph (and therefore, on the execution order).

Another informative page on this matter is available [here](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-task.html).